# How to install visual studio 2019 from an ISO file without internet

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2019

I have copied visual studio 2019 as an ISO file from another computer, and I have the serial key and all data and packages. Its size more than 22GB. I want to install it offline, without using any internet connection to download its data, I have all data as I said.

The problem is, when I open the  setup.exe , screens appear don't provide any option to select packages data from local storage, the only allowed way is to download them from internet.
I don't want to download any data, I want make it using the data downloaded on my local computer because the size of data is very large. Is there any way to solve this issue?

I searched about some solutions such as installing certificates before the setup and opening the setup.exe as administrator, and using cmd with layout, but none of them were correct for my case.

Comment: Visit these links, will help you: 1- https://superuser.com/questions/1473733/visual-studio-install-offline-installer-with-no-network         2- https://www.windowsmode.com/download-visual-studio-2019-for-windows-10/            3- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio         if they helped you, inform us